# Apply AOP aspect in OSGI reference

Tags: spring, reference, osgi, aop, aspect

Is it possible to apply an AOP aspect in an OSGI reference?

I have two bundles, bundle A expose a service that bundle B is able to consume it.
Bundle B has a bean reference, and I want to apply AOP aspect to this reference.
I want to use monitoring using JMX.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Equinox OSGi container you can use [Equinox Weaving](http://eclipse.org/equinox/weaving/) feature to apply AspectJ AOP on various bundles.